# Eclipse: project properties update: Element {urn:partner.soap.sforce.com}returnFieldDataTypes invalid

Tags: apex, force.com, ide, eclipse, force.com-ide

A newbie developer here... thx in advance for all your help!

I am trying to set up eclipse for salesforce.
Keep getting this error on Eclipse Mars.1 and Eclipse Kelper.

[Unable to update project properties:

Element {urn:partner.soap.sforce.com}returnFieldDataTypes invalid at this location]

other info: 
Prior to this, I just setup github and imported project on Eclipse. 
I'm using Mac OSx el capitan version 10.11 Beta (15A279b) 64

Feel free to ask any Qs that might help fix the problem.

screen shot also attached [image]

Comment: tried on a different computer (PC and worked...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The latest version of the Force.com IDE connects to API36, but most orgs are still on API 35. Uninstall the current version of the Force.com IDE in eclipse (look at the help/about menu for the about window that shows for installed software and lets you uninstall selected packages), then when you go to add new software uncheck the "show only latest versions" checkbox and install the API 35 version.

I just ran into this, and it resolved the issue for me.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you Kibitzer! Will try this and report back with results.

Comment: This happened to me when I tried to update the plugin when v35 came out.  Had to do these exact steps back then.  Thanks @kibitzer

Comment: its good, it resolved my issue,